# AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute

Tags: linux, ansible

I'm using Ansible and I'm getting this error after running my playbook.

This is my playbook:

```
---
- name: Set 192.168.122.4 Hostname
  hosts: 192.168.122.4
  gather_facts: false
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name : Name 4
      hostname:
        name:  ansible1.example.com

- name: Set 192.168.122.5 Hostname
  hosts: 192.168.122.5
  gather_facts: false
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name : Name 5
      hostname:
        name: ansible2.example.com

- name: Manage Hosts File
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  become: true
  tasks:
    
    - name: Deploy Hosts Template
      template:
        src: hosts.j2
        dest: /etc/hosts
```

This is my Template

```
# Managed by Ansible
127.0.0.1 localhost
{% for host in groups['all'] %}
{{ hostvars[host]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }} {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_fqdn'] }} {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_hostname'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

I get this error:

`AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'ansible_default_ipv4`

I have tried using the debug module to see if I get back a response from `ansible_default_ipv4`, and I get a list there including the address, which is what I want. So its not the case that the remote servers don't have that setup, they do, the info is there, but just how do I retrieve it so I can populate this `/etc/hosts` file.

BUT I've found out that it's not about the `ansible_default_ipv4` per se, because it will give the same error for another object.

So I'm guessing that its something to do with these magic variables from the Template.

My references are:

RHCE 8 - Ansible RHCE - Using Jinja Templates to Populate Host Files
by theurbanpenguin on YouTube, look it up

Comment: The template worked fine for me.  Can you add your inventory file to the question?

Comment: Those facts are not set for hosts with `gather_facts: false`, since that's the very thing which fact gathering is designed to expose; you can test this theory by adding `- setup: {}` right before your `- template:` task and it should start to work for all hosts

Comment: @mdaniel He's got `gather_facts: true` set on the play in which he is calling the template.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a complete output of runing your playbook ? There must be something we don't see here. I don't see any problems with your template. You should also add your inventory.

Comment: I would paste the entire thing but I just can't copy from my virtual box virtual machine and paste here

Comment: @Jack, and Zeitounator,  the problem was my inventory, I left a server that wasn't operational in there and once I removed it, it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @LuanMoreira The hostnames and IP addresses should be in the inventory, not in the playbooks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks @Jack @Zeitounator, the issue was on my inventory. So apparently if you leave a server on your inventory that you are not using, for example, my inventory was

10.0.2.[4:7]

but I left my [7] machine off, once I removed and made my inventory like

10.0.2.[4:6] it started working.

So Im guessing that if you have a machine listed in your inventory that you are not using anymore it can cause issues with magic variables.

My lesson here is to keep inventory file clean.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem when it comes to upgrading one/some server in the inventory (limiting host) why I should remove it permanently. I think there is something still unclear

Comment: I had the same problem when I used -l 'server1.example.com' but when i changed -l 'all' it worked. The template has for host in groups['all'] , while not using the playbook for 'all' hosts.

Comment: This worked for me as well, thank you. Just commented out the server that was down

Answer (score -3):

you must specify hosts:all

gathering: This only affects the gathering done by a play's gather_facts directive,