# Ansible for loop that fails when any of the inventory hosts are down/unreachable

Tags: ansible

I am working on a playbook that, among other things, creates a local file which contains all hosts that are running Docker. It goes something like this:

```yaml
- name: Retrieve list of hosts that match certain attributes
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  become: true

  tasks:

  - name: Check servers where Docker is running
    systemd:
      name: docker
    register: is_docker_service_running

  - name: Write to file all servers where docker is running
    copy:
      content: |
        {% for host in groups['all'] %}
        {% if hostvars[host].is_docker_service_running.status.ActiveState == 'active' %}{{ hostvars[host].inventory_hostname }}
        {% endif -%}
        {% endfor %}
      dest: /tmp/servers_with_docker
    delegate_to: localhost
```

This works well, except for when... it doesn't. I've noticed that, when one of my inventory hosts is down/unreachable, the whole play will fail (even though the other 200+ hosts are alive and kicking).

This is the error which appears for each of the 200+ hosts, even for those that are actually reachable:

```
fatal: [alive-host1 -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'is_docker_service_running'. 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'is_docker_service_running'
fatal: [alive-host2 -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'is_docker_service_running'. 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'is_docker_service_running'
fatal: [alive-host3 -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'is_docker_service_running'. 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'is_docker_service_running'
fatal: [alive-host4 -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'is_docker_service_running'. 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'is_docker_service_running'
[...]
[...]
```

If I remove/comment out the affected host from the inventory, everything will be back to normal.

Now, I realize that I'm targeting 'all' hosts, but shouldn't Ansible disregard the unreachable host, especially since I'm also gathering facts beforehand? Am I missing something obvious, is there a way to make sure that my loop will completely ignore any unreachable host?

I've found questions from other users who encountered the same issue, but the answer to those questions never addressed the actual underlying cause/why this is happening, they merely 'fixed' the effect (i.e.: removing the unreachable host from the inventory): [AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64147785/ansibleundefinedvariable-ansible-vars-hostvars-hostvarsvars-object-has-no-att)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What fails is that your are looping in your template on the `all` group including hosts that might have previously fail and which do not contain any facts. Just change that loop to use the [`ansible_play_hosts` magic variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#term-ansible_play_hosts) which contains the current hosts in the loop excluding failed ones:

```
...
{% for host in ansible_play_hosts %}
...
```